# How should I use font file for bold, italic, etc in html canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas, fonts

I downloaded a few fonts from google font and there are some font files for `bold, italic, light, thin` etc. Let's take `Robot` as an example, these are two font files I downloaded: `Roboto-Bold.ttf, Roboto-Regular.ttf`.

I wonder how should I use the file with `Bold`? What is the difference if I pick the regular font file with below code:

```
canvasContext.font = `bold 20px Robot`
```

The above code defines the `bold` for the `Robot` font family. Do I need to import `Roboto-Bold.ttf` file for the `bold` in this case? The same question for `italic`, `light`, `thin` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to define your font in css using `@font-face` with all the weights. Define same `font-name` for all the styles, just differentiate them with `font-weight` like below

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("Roboto-Regular.ttf");
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("Roboto-Bold.ttf");
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("Roboto-light.ttf");
  font-weight: 300;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  src: url("Roboto-thin.ttf");
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

and then use it in your elements like

```
element {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight:100; /* for Thin */
  font-weight:300; /* for Light */
  font-weight:normal; /* for Regular */
  font-weight:bold; /* for Bold */
}
```

*[Or you can use html `<link>` to embed your font like](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto:100,300,400,400i,500)*

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,400i,500" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: There are some font files don't have `*-bold, *-light`. How can I apply the bold, light styles on them?

Comment: @ZhaoYi you can't....you will need their font files(.ttf) with bold and light style...

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to use google font just go to fonts.google.com & select font then customize it**

**After finishing your customization go to "EMBED"**

1. Copy the link & paste it into your html head section.
2. Copy the font family name & paste into your css file selector like below.

> ```
> canvas {
>  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
>  font-weight: thin/normal/bold/bolder; // Choose any option
>  font-style: normal/italic/oblique;  // Choose any option
>  font-size: 20px;
> }
> ```

[image: Google Font Customization]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must link file font to your project

```
<style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'Athiti';
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: 400;
            src: local('Athiti'), local('Athiti-Regular'), url('fonts/Athiti-Regular.ttf') format("truetype");
        }
</style>
```

When you call font name

```
 <div class="container" style="font-family: 'Athiti' font-size: 16px; ">
<b> Font Bold </b>
</dib>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Bold font

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'RobotoBold';
    src: url('./Roboto-Bold.ttf');
}
```

And use `canvasContext.font = 20px RobotoBold`

You need to import one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to import each tff file , however the regular version still can be made bold etc in some/most family fonts , for example you will have the normal bold weight 400 , but if you want to get other bold variations e.g 500 600 700 you will need to import the bold variation of the font